# DER duda con solución a enunciado

Tags: base-de-datos

tengo una duda a si la solución planteada en el siguiente DER puede ser considerada. El enunciado expone que un cliente puede autorizar a un tercero a retirar el vehiculo (vehiculos de una determinada reserva). Un cliente puede realizar muchas reservas y una reserva sólo pertenece a un cliente (al no tener muchos a muchos no puedo colocar al tercero aqui). ¿ESta bien que suponiendo que sólo sea un trecero por cliente (el enunciaado no lo expone), lo determine como atributo de la entidad cliente?

[image: DER eunciados]

Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo!!

**Con respecto al punto 2:** Si un cliente puede autorizar a un tercero (puede ser que el cliente no le interese contar con esa posibilidad), una relación autoriza entre cliente 0..1 y tercero 1..M con tercero y aprovechar esto para que tercero se relacione con incluye:

[image: Diagrama resolución]

Comment: Ufff... no, no, no te líes... las intenciones son buenas, pero estás duplicando datos. ¿Qué pasaría si un autorizado también fuera cliente? Pues que ya estarías guardando dos veces su teléfono ¡REDUNDANCIA! Elimina `autoriza` y `TERCERO` y traza la línea directamente de `incluye` a `CLIENTE`

Comment: Perfecto, gracias por la paciencia me costo comprender lo de una tabla para contemplar dos situaciones (cliente y tercero). No tenía expriencia con ello. Le agradezco mucho!!

Comment: Gracias a ti por intentarlo e insistir hasta verlo. Es la forma de aprender. Fíjate en que, tanto clientes como terceros, son personas modeladas por los mismos atributos, así que necesariamente deben pertenecer al mismo grupo de entidades (entidad). Conforme vayas avanzando y llegues a implementarlo físicamente, irás viéndolo cada vez más claro. Al final todo serán tablas y campos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intentaré ser lo más objetivo posible para que la pregunta no sea cerrada por basarse en opiniones. Sin perjuicio de que este enunciado admita varias soluciones válidas, justificaré con argumentos cada propuesta.

- Si metes al tercero en la relación `incluye` tendrás la opción de cambiar de tercero en cada alquiler. Si va ligado al cliente, nunca podrá cambiar de tercero.
- El código de vehículo, además de en la relación `incluye` como el `NROIdentificacion` de la reserva, también debería estar en `vehículo`, pues es algo característico del vehículo, entiendo que como la matrícula.
- Así mismo, el precio de alquiler, aunque quieras guardar un precio de referencia en el `vehículo`, también debería guardarse en la relación `incluye` pues, de lo contrario, trabajarías con un esquema de precios fijo que no admitiría oscilaciones de precios.

Por lo demás, tiene bastante buena pinta. Yo lo implementaría...

**Respuestas a los comentarios**

En caso de incluir al `tercero` en `incluye`:

- ¿La relación entre el `cliente` y el `tercero` es transitiva, por consulta la puedo establecer no?

  Efectivamente, a través de `incluye`, `reserva`, `tiene` y, finalmente `cliente`. Combinando las tablas con un `JOIN` lo obtienes.
- ¿Si el tercero tuviera datos (`nombre`, `teléfono`), podrían ser atributos de `incluye`?

  Eso te obligaría a registrar los datos de contacto del tercero cada vez que fueran autorizado para alquilar un vehículo. Uniendo directamente `incluye` con `cliente`, aprovecharías la tabla `clientes` para guardar los datos de los autorizados. El bucle no implica redundancia porque la semántica de `autorizado` y `cliente` están perfectamente diferenciadas, no hay redundancia, al contrario, evitas duplicar datos.
- Si el cliente no manda a un tercero y él retira el/los autos ¿no hay problema tener muchos `null` en incluye?

  Ninguno, un `NULL` es un dato como cualquier otro. Es un poco feo, pero lo queremos igual :) Te servirá para identificar aquellos vehículos que ha recogido directamente el cliente.

Anímate a implementarlo en MySQL y te echamos una mano con las consultas, que de este diseño te van a salir unas cuantas divertidas.

Comment: Gracias por su tiempo, en caso de incluir al tercero en incluye: a.¿La relación entre el cliente y el tercero es transitiva, por consulta la puedo establecer no? b.¿Si el tercero tuviera datos (nombre, teléfono), podrian ser atributos de incluye? c. Si el cliente no manda un tercero y él retira el/los autos ¿no hay problema tener muchos null en incluye?

Comment: Edito la pregunta para tratar el punto 2.

Comment: Ufff... no, no, no te líes... las intenciones son buenas, pero estás duplicando datos. ¿Qué pasaría si un autorizado también fuera cliente? Pues que ya estarías guardando dos veces su teléfono ¡REDUNDANCIA! Elimina `autoriza` y `TERCERO` y traza la línea directamente de `incluye` a `CLIENTE`

Comment: Perfecto, gracias por la paciencia me costo comprender lo de una tabla para contemplar dos situaciones (cliente y tercero). No tenía experiencia con ello. Le agradezco mucho!!